# Can't get -contains in powershell to work like expected

Tags: arrays, powershell, contains

I'm trying to write a script in Powershell that will match extensions of file names. This is what I have so far:

```
$location = $args[0];

[String]$extensions = @(".mkv", ".mp4", ".avi", ".wmv");
$pruneSize = 41240000;

Set-Location $location;

Get-ChildItem -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
    If($extensions -contains $_.Extension) {
        Write-Host "Found it";
    }
    else {
        Write-Host $_.Extension not found in $extensions;
    }
}
```

And here is the output:

```
.mp4 not found in .mkv .mp4 .avi .wmv
.bat not found in .mkv .mp4 .avi .wmv
.bat not found in .mkv .mp4 .avi .wmv
```

So it seems that it should work but it doesn't. If I switch "-contains" to "-match" then it works, though I don't want to use match as it seems that -contains should be what I really want and is more accurate for what I need. Am I missing some quirk of powershell?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing the `[String]` from before `$extensions`

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you're casting an array to `String` (multiple object -> one object). This joins the extensions together with a space between each item.

```
[String]$extensions = @(".mkv", ".mp4", ".avi", ".wmv");

$extensions
.mkv .mp4 .avi .wmv
```

`-contains` is used to look for an item in an array. So drop the cast to string and all will be fine.

```
$extensions = @(".mkv", ".mp4", ".avi", ".wmv");

$extensions -contains ".mp4"
True
```